# How to structure my files like this image?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, web-applications

I created a new asp.net core razor web application. How to make my files look like the left side of this image?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This feature is called **File Nesting** or **File Grouping** in Visual Studio. However, it's not implemented in VSCode yet. There's a pull request in VSCode's GitHub for this feature that you can use : https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/13754

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling on this question in 2022...

1. in VSCode, open Settings
2. search for "filenesting"
3. set Explorer > File Nesting: Enabled
4. add patterns to Explorer > File Nesting: Patterns (I've provided a few examples below beyond the defaults)

[image: vscode settings]